# Macro breaks only in `eval-expression` (`M-:`)

Tags: elisp-macros, eval-expression

I have a macro which unpacks a list into variables, as if by `setq`:

```lisp
(unpack (a b c) '(1 2 3))
```

is roughly comparable to

```lisp
(setq a 1)
(setq b 2)
(setq c 3)
```

The way I did that initially was by having the macro expand to a `dolist` on the variable names, where each iteration did one `(setq variable-name (car the-list))` and manually stepped through the value list with `(setq the-list (cdr the-list))`:

```lisp
(defmacro unpack (names list)
    `(let ((--unpack-- ,list))
        (dolist (name ',names)
            (eval (list 'setq name '(car --unpack--)))
            (setq --unpack-- (cdr --unpack--)))))
```

But this had a surprising bug: if I used `unpack` in my init file, or evaluated calls to `unpack` with `eval-last-sexp` in a buffer, it worked fine, but if I evaluated calls to `unpack` in the minibuffer during `eval-expression` (`M-:`), it failed with `Lisp error: (void-variable --unpack--)`.

For example, `M-:` `(unpack (test1 test2) '(1 2))` `RET` leads to:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable --unpack--)
  (car --unpack--)
  (setq test1 (car --unpack--))
  eval((setq test1 (car --unpack--)))
  (let ((name (car --dolist-tail--))) (eval (list 'setq name '(car --unpack--))) (setq --unpack-- (cdr --unpack--)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (let ((name (car --dolist-tail--))) (eval (list 'setq name '(car --unpack--))) (setq --unpack-- (cdr --unpack--)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- '(test1 test2))) (while --dolist-tail-- (let ((name (car --dolist-tail--))) (eval (list 'setq name '(car --unpack--))) (setq --unpack-- (cdr --unpack--)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))))
  (let ((--unpack-- '(1 2))) (let ((--dolist-tail-- '(test1 test2))) (while --dolist-tail-- (let ((name (car --dolist-tail--))) (eval (list 'setq name '(car --unpack--))) (setq --unpack-- (cdr --unpack--)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))))
  eval-expression((unpack (test1 test2) '(1 2)) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (unpack (test1 test2) '(1 2)) nil nil 127)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Here's another variant of `unpack` which **doesn't** have this problem: instead of building a `dolist` form, I do the `dolist` in the macro itself and build one `(setq ...)` form:

```lisp
(defmacro unpack (names list)
    (let* ((setq-form (list 'setq))
           (last-cons setq-form)
           (cdr-chain '--unpack--))
        (dolist (name names)
            (setcdr last-cons (list name (list 'car cdr-chain)))
            (setq cdr-chain (list 'cdr cdr-chain))
            (setq last-cons (cddr last-cons)))
        `(let ((--unpack-- ,list)) ,setq-form nil)))
```

But I don't understand why the first one works fine in normal usage yet fails in `M-:`.

Comment: Maybe yours is an exercise and my comment is useless but you know you can write `(setq a 1 b 2 c 3)`, right? If you have the lists of names and values then you could use `(seq-mapn #'set '(a b c) '(1 2 3))` ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html)).

Comment: I just discovered that there's also `seq-setq`: `(seq-setq (a b c) '(1 2 3))` works like `unpack`.

Comment: @ArchStanton re: `seq-setq`: ah, excellent, I knew there must've been a built-in equivalent somewhere. (I knew about pcase, but found it off-puttingly complex for my needs. I see that `seq-setq` uses pcase internally, but at least it hides all that complexity so I don't have to deal with it behind an equally clear and self-descriptive interface. And it handles the `&rest` case!) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error because you use `eval`.

> `(eval FORM &optional LEXICAL)`
>
> Evaluate `FORM` and return its value.  
> If `LEXICAL` is t, evaluate using lexical scoping.  
> `LEXICAL` can also be an actual lexical environment, in the form of an alist mapping symbols to their value.

You can write these:

```lisp
(eval 'teeest '((teeest . 42)))
;; => 42

(eval '(let ((teeest 43))
         teeest) t)
;; => 43
```

But you shouldn't expect

```lisp
(let ((teeest 44))
  (eval 'teeest))
```

to return `44` if you don't mark `teeest` as a special variable (e.g., by using `defvar`).

This is because

> Note that unlike dynamic variables which are tied to the symbol object itself, the relationship between lexical variables and symbols is only present in the interpreter (or compiler).  
> Therefore, **functions which take a symbol argument** (like `symbol-value`, `boundp`, and `set`) **can only retrieve or modify a variable’s dynamic binding** (i.e., the contents of its symbol’s value cell).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I had a strong suspicion it was due to the eval, but I didn't really understand why.

Comment: Although... I still can't say I fully understand why it seemed to work in some cases... I didn't have any `defvar`, `defconst`, or `setq` outside of `(let ...)` for `--unpack--` anywhere in my code that I'm aware of.

Comment: @mtraceur: A little difficult for me to speculate as to why, because I haven't actually experienced your Emacs and don't know exactly what's going on before and after.